# Polymer Multiple Entry Points

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In the polymer.json file is there anyway to point to multiple points of entry?

`"entrypoint": ["index.html", "index2.html", "index3.html"]`

Or would it be best just to include the other indexes in the fragments section?

This would be for a domain and some sub domains.

`example.com`
`app.example.com`
`shop.example.com`

I don't really need this but it would be nice to have one folder for production.

I'm just adding text to satisfy the validation.

Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remember a polymer "application" is a single application, it's a single page, except it's not really a page at all, it's an application.

Having multiple entrypoints doesn't make sense, because loading that entry point is really just loading an application specified in that file... index.html is a sort of manifest and bootstrap that starts your application.

If you have multiple entry points, these are different applications, which will involve page load. Either build them as three different apps, and share the common code in libraries of your custom elements, etc, or refactor your applications so there is one index.html/app load entrypoint, and load the features that make up index2.html and index3.html as fragments.

Perhaps all your index?.html files are really views, different "screens" in your application, and you should make them all fragments, and in index.html have the shared code load the original index123.html's as views.